# web scraping after login redirect

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape data from a web-page "blocked" by a login redirect. So I used `selenium` to input all the necessary login info and navigate to where the data is. however `selenium`dose not support extracting headers and other text data as far as I know, meaning I would have to use another web-scraping tool like `beautiful soup`. However those tools require a direct URL link which will redirect that tool to the login page anyway.

Is there a way I can ether use `selenium` to extract data or enable another tool to interact with the already logged in `selenium` tool to extract data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the pagesource and feed it into beautiful soup

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

But look up the code in the browser (F12 network) and see if the login is a restapi service, then it is much easier to use requests and http.cookiejar and create proper cookies you can inject into selenum.

Comment: loading the page_source into the html worked perfectly first time, thanks.